# MVC FoolProof Validation showing exception while calling SaveChange method

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, foolproof-validation

This question mayt sound duplicate but I am not satisfied with any of the answers as some are suggesting `MVC Foolproof validaiton` for conditional validaiton and some tells it dont work well with entity framework

I am using `MVC Foolproof RequiredIf validation` in my project.It works well on clientside and is validation is working on server side as well.

```
 [RequiredIf("STCompulsory",Operator.EqualTo,true,ErrorMessage="Please enter Registration No")]
    public string STRegNo { get; set; }
```

But when i call `db.Savechanges()` to insert data an exception is coming

```
An unexpected exception was thrown during validation of 'STRegNo' when invoking 
Foolproof.RequiredIfAttribute.IsValid. See the inner exception for details.
```

**InnerException**

```
The method or operation is not implemented.
```

Comment: Is this applied to a view model or your actual data model?

Comment: Thanks for the reply..Its applied to actual data model..

Comment: Not a good idea. And yes, there are some issues with using foolproof validations and EF so best to use a view model. Also it really only needs to be `[RequiredIf("STCompulsory", true, ErrorMessage = "..")]`

Comment: Thanks mate.You saved me again.If you post the answer i will accept it so that it helps others having similar issue..

Comment: @StephenMuecke:If possible kinldy look into [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346189/complex-custom-validation-in-foolproof-validation)

Comment: Were you wanting client side validation for that?

Comment: Yes..both client and server side validation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the `Operator.EqualTo` parameter and it can be simply

```
[RequiredIf("STCompulsory", true, ErrorMessage="Please enter Registration No")
public string STRegNo { get; set; }
```

You are correct in that the foolproof `[RequiredIf]` attribute does have some problems with EF and it is discussed in detail in [this work issue](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/workitem/15609) (along with some suggested changes).

The easiest solution is to use a view model rather than your data model in the view, and apply the attribute to the view model property.